# Need to submit the register info in eloqua from Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Need to post the registration info to eloqua too.

I am using Drupal 6.14

Comment: Uhh sorry, but your question is really not clear at all. What exactly are you asking? What is eloqua?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't even a question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't ask the original question, but I might be able to shed a little more light. I am a consultant, and I work at Eloqua.
Eloqua is a marketing automation database. Having the registrations flow from Drupal into Eloqua would allow things like moving that info over into a CRM system, or sending a follow up email with the registration details.
Our clients have integrated with other CMS systems.
Now, in terms of the registrations, there are a couple of ways Eloqua could receive that data. Perhaps the simplest way would be through some sort of form repost, IF that is allowed in Drupal. So, someone would register, that data would enter Drupal, and then be reposted into Eloqua. It looks like people ([including the initial poste](http://drupal.org/node/362153)r) have been able to make this work succesfully on regular forms The other way would be to utilize Eloqua's API. This would require someone to build out a module that would facilitate that.